# 3 rotation values to work out rotation in degrees

Tags: algorithms, rotations, quaternions

I am currently working with the Oculus headset and dealing with the Z axis.

With the software I have, the values I can retrieve are limited and I was hoping someone could help me find a solution to an interesting problem of finding the degree of the headset using these values.

I have 3 values that change dependent on the degree on the z axis As I rotate the gyro within the headset positively:

Values - L, M, N

[image: Diagram]

They are true numbers when at 0,90,180 and 270 degrees. While approaching that point the increment or decrements from the previous value. (i.e at 45* it would be 0.5)

Q:*Can anyone help me create a algorithm that I can add any 3 values and retrieve the degree of rotation?*

Many thanks,

MC

Comment: Is $N$ always equal to $-M$? Do the values really increment/decrement linearly with angle (giving a sawtooth function of angle with value $0.5$ at $45$ degrees) or are they sinusoidal (value approximately $0.7$ at $45$ degrees)?

Comment: Yeah, these values share a relationship. As one change, the other two change by the same amount. (i.e L at 45 degrees = 0.5, M = 0.5, N = -0.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description, it seems these are not smooth functions of angle
but instead are piecewise linear functions of the angle.
So a formula involving atan2 or something like that is not going to work.

As a first step, I would split the algorithm into two cases:

- when $M \geq 0$
- when $M < 0$

In each case, you can write the angle of rotation as a linear function of $L$ alone.

The value of $N$ adds no information since you can deduce it from $M$,
so you can ignore it.

This algorithm is prone to errors near $0$ degrees and $180$ degrees if
the slope of $L$ does not change exactly when $M$ reaches zero.
A more robust algorithm would use four cases:

- when $M \geq 0.5$
- when $M \leq -0.5$
- when $-0.5 < M < 0.5$ and $L > 0$
- when $-0.5 < M < 0.5$ and $L < 0$

The first two cases are just like the two cases before; in the last two
cases, however, the angle is a linear function of $M$ alone.

This is all assuming that $L = M = 0.5$ at $45$ degrees, which I
still find surprising although not impossible.

I'm sure this starts to get much more complicated very quickly if you
start turning the headset in any way that is not just a rotation around
the $z$ axis.

Comment: Thanks for this David, luckily I only need to worry about the Z axis. Ill batter in and see how I get on. All the best.

Comment: OK, good luck. I added a four-case algorithm in case the outputs of the gyro aren't precisely synchronized near 0 and 180 degrees. If you don't have a problem near those angles with the first algorithm then you probably don't need the more complicated one.

Comment: Hi David, after writing the algorithm you were correct, 45 degrees = 0.7 approx. Does this change anything at all?